# Archive Widget - Count only parent posts

Tags: filters, widgets, archives

I'm currently using a filter applied to the Archive Widget.
It's successfully filtering posts from the specific category (26) but now I also want to filter only PARENT posts, in order to count only PARENT posts from this category.

I'm currently using the following, but not working:

```
function my_nav_archives($args){
    $args['cat'] = 26;
    $args['post_parent'] = 0;

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'widget_archives_args', 'my_nav_archives' );
```

Is there any other argument I can use?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand the definition of a Parent Post as it is used in the Wordpress structure.  Pages (a type of post within WP) can have a hierarchical with PARENTS.  Posts, by default, cannot. It would require a special plugin to add that hierarchy.   Without that special structure, `$args['post_parent']=0` should return all posts in `$args['cat']=26`.  Have you added a plugin to establish hierarchical Posts?

Comment: Sorry I've not made that clear... Yes, I've added an ACTION to my functions.php that enables hierarchy in posts, using the code on the accepted answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750931/wordpress-how-to-add-hierarchy-to-posts

Comment: Looking more closely at [Wordpress Core](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_widget_archives/) , I'm actually surprised that your cat argument works. It appears the available arguments are totally different from WP_Query args. Take a look at `function widget($args,$instance)` beginning on line 42, and compare it to [the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives). It would appear you just got lucky with `$args['cat']`.  Hope somebody can prove me wrong and find a solution for you...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I found a sample that was close.  I have modified it to be similar to what you want.  I'm not sure it is 100%, but it should get you really close:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','wpse_filter_parents_only');

function wpse_filter_parents_only($query){
    if (!is_admin() && is_category('26')){
        $query->set('post_parent',0);
    }
    return $query;
}
```

This should update what WP_Query retrieves from the database, and only for category 26.  If you need this to affect multiple categories, stuff them into an array and insert the array like this: `is_category($cats)`.

Hope this helps!